# Jenkins git plugin: How to configure different fetch and push git remotes?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins project which has a git checkout url. The Jenkins master is configured with git-Jenkins plugin version 2.2.10_2 (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin).

I wanted to check if there is any way to provide different git remotes for fetch and push.

```
e.g: $ git remote -v
origin  git@<read-only-git>.com:org/repo.git (fetch) 
origin  git@<read-write-git>.com:org/repo.git (push)
```

The use case here is to use a read only source for clones and push any changes back to a read-write source. There is an external synchronization mechanism to update the read only copy.

Thank you,

-Mayur

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `--push` option of `git remote set-url`.

Assuming you'd cloned from the read-only repo:

**Before**

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@<read-only-git>.com:org/repo.git (fetch) 
origin  git@<read-only-git>.com:org/repo.git (push)
```

**Command**

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@<read-write-git>.com:org/repo.git
```

**After**

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@<read-only-git>.com:org/repo.git (fetch) 
origin  git@<read-write-git>.com:org/repo.git (push)
```